# How to fill values into a new column by iterating a defined function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

Self-study really requires me a lot of effort, and after wasting alot of time over this issue I decided to come here and ask for help. So, I'm using Google api for my project, which look like below:

```html
def sample_analyze_sentiment(text_content):
    """
    Analyzing Sentiment in a String

    Args:
      text_content The text content to analyze
    """

    client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()

    # text_content = 'I am so happy and joyful.'

    # Available types: PLAIN_TEXT, HTML
    type_ = language_v1.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT

    # Optional. If not specified, the language is automatically detected.
    # For list of supported languages:
    # https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/languages
    language = "en"
    document = {"content": text_content, "type_": type_, "language": language}

    # Available values: NONE, UTF8, UTF16, UTF32
    encoding_type = language_v1.EncodingType.UTF8

    response = client.analyze_sentiment(request = {'document': document, 'encoding_type': encoding_type})
    # Get overall sentiment of the input document
    print(format(response.document_sentiment.score))
```

And what I want to do is iterating text data through this function to get the sentiment score of each rows.

```html
df = pd.read_csv('Final.csv')
for items in df['Text']:
    sample_analyze_sentiment(items)
```

*Then mapping it into a new column of the dataframe* (this is where I dont know how). My function return string of floats but it is definitely nonetype, so I think I cant do this. But, I still doubt cause it seem doable.

*Help please*.

Comment: Please post an expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the function to the `'Text'` column in your dataframe. In order to do so, you have to return yur result (i.e. the sentiment) from your function:

```
def sample_analyze_sentiment(text_content):
    """
    Analyzing Sentiment in a String

    Args:
      text_content The text content to analyze
    """

    client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()

    # text_content = 'I am so happy and joyful.'

    # Available types: PLAIN_TEXT, HTML
    type_ = language_v1.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT

    # Optional. If not specified, the language is automatically detected.
    # For list of supported languages:
    # https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/languages
    language = "en"
    document = {"content": text_content, "type_": type_, "language": language}

    # Available values: NONE, UTF8, UTF16, UTF32
    encoding_type = language_v1.EncodingType.UTF8

    response = client.analyze_sentiment(request = {'document': document, 'encoding_type': encoding_type})
    # Get overall sentiment of the input document
    return format(response.document_sentiment.score)
```

Then it should be possible to create a new column `'sentiment'` in your dataframe with the following line:

```
df['sentiment'] = df['Text'].apply(sample_analyze_sentiment)
```

Comment: This did work except for the result of the sentiment column will be none for all the rows cause the function return Nonetype. Can I use astype for this ? How should I fix this ?

Comment: Sorry rookie mistake should not use print but return istead thank you this is the right answer